# Heroku custom clock process fails to run at each interval using cron

Tags: node.js, heroku, cron

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm trying to follow [this](http://blog.andyjiang.com/intermediate-cron-jobs-with-heroku/) article. I have the following Procfile:

```
web: node index.js
worker: node bot.js
clock: node clock.js
```

and inside my clock.js, I have:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var bot = require('./bot.js');

new CronJob({
    cronTime: "* * * * *",
    onTick: bot.start(),
    start: true,
    timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
});
```

and my bot.js is structured like so:

```
var config = require('./config');
// ... other includes

module.exports = {
    start: function() {
        // code
    }
}
```

My structure matches the article pretty much exactly, but what's going on? Here are my logs:

```
2016-12-16T06:00:48.935847+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2016-12-16T06:00:49.332925+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node bot.js`
2016-12-16T06:00:49.736519+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: Starting process with command `node clock.js`
2016-12-16T06:00:50.058125+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-12-16T06:00:50.395082+00:00 heroku[clock.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-12-16T06:00:51.899971+00:00 app[web.1]: app running on port 21470
2016-12-16T06:00:52.505353+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2016-12-16T06:00:52.491705+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-12-16T06:00:52.698864+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

So I can see that I'm starting up the worker (which does nothing) and it then crashes. Then my clock starts up , but never calls the worker again? It's definitely not starting up every minute.

Is the article I followed old and no longer applies? How should I correctly call the worker?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a process.exit(0) command somewhere in bot.start()?

Heroku crashes a dyno when it comes across the command (see [this link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos) for more info). If you remove that, it should potentially solve the problem. It would be helpful to post the full bot.start function to verify.